# Pointer event javascript

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

What do usePointerCapture and releasePointerCapture actually do on pointer events, what are the uses of these methods and how to use them

Some documentation such as mdn does not explain it in detail

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the simple example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture).

Click the box and then drag diagonally down. You will see the box stops and jumps back to the cursor ones you reenter the div.

```js
function beginSliding(e) {
  slider.onpointermove = slide;
}

function stopSliding(e) {
  slider.onpointermove = null;
}

function slide(e) {
  slider.style.transform = `translate(${e.clientX - 70}px)`;
}

const slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.onpointerdown = beginSliding;
slider.onpointerup = stopSliding;
```

```css
div {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fbe;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">SLIDE ME</div>
```

By using [setPointerCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture) we can capture all pointer events (even outside the target div) until we release them with [releasePointerCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/releasePointerCapture).

If we apply this to our example, we can see that the box keeps moving smoothly even if we leave the div.

```js
function beginSliding(e) {
  slider.onpointermove = slide;
  slider.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
}

function stopSliding(e) {
  slider.onpointermove = null;
  slider.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
}

function slide(e) {
  slider.style.transform = `translate(${e.clientX - 70}px)`;
}

const slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.onpointerdown = beginSliding;
slider.onpointerup = stopSliding;
```

```css
div {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fbe;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">SLIDE ME</div>
```